# std::throw_with_nested expects default constructor for virtual base class of Exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, libstdc++

Why does this not compile (tried with Clang 3.4.2 and GCC versions 4.7.4, 4.8.3 and 4.9.1):

```
#include <exception>

struct Base {
  inline Base(int) {}
  virtual void f() {}
};

struct Derived: virtual Base {
  inline Derived() : Base(42) {}
};

int main() {
  std::throw_with_nested(Derived());
  return 0;
}
```

Errors from GCC 4.9.1:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/exception:163:0,
                from test.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/bits/nested_exception.h: In instantiation of 'std::_Nested_exception<_Except>::_Nested_exception(_Except&&) [with _Except = Derived]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/bits/nested_exception.h:126:60:   required from 'void std::__throw_with_nested(_Ex&&, ...) [with _Ex = Derived]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/bits/nested_exception.h:140:58:   required from 'void std::throw_with_nested(_Ex) [with _Ex = Derived]'
test.cpp:13:35:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/bits/nested_exception.h:81:45: error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()'
      : _Except(static_cast<_Except&&>(__ex))
                                            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.1/include/g++-v4/bits/nested_exception.h:81:45: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:4:10: note: Base::Base(int)
  inline Base(int) {}
          ^
test.cpp:4:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)
struct Base {
        ^
test.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:3:8: note: constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)
test.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

If I omit the `virtual` keyword I get no errors. Is this a GCC and Clang or libstd++ bug, or am I doing something wrong?

PS: Note that `virtual void f() {}` is a workaround for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324262/stdthrow-with-nested-expects-polymorphic-type-in-c11) [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62154).

Comment: If you declare a member inside the declaration of the class, it's redundant to mark them `inline`: "A function defined within a class definition is an inline function." §7.1.2 [dcl.fct.spec]

Comment: Why do you do a virtual inheritance exactly ?

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy yes missed struct, edited my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard states:

> For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most derived object shall contain a single base class subobject of that type.
>
> §10.1 [class.mi]

Also, with respect to `std::throw_with_nested`:

> `[[noreturn]] template <class T> void throw_with_nested(T&& t);`
>
> Let `U` be `remove_reference<T>::type`.
>
> *Requires:* `U` shall be `CopyConstructible`.
>
> *Throws:* if `U` is a non-union class type not derived from `nested_exception`, an exception of unspecified type that is publicly derived from both `U` and `nested_exception` and constructed from `std::forward<T>(t)`, otherwise `std::forward<T>(t)`.
>
> §18.8.6 [except.nested]

If you look in `bits/nested_exception.h`, you'll find the following, which is the base class that the library creates for `std::throw_with_nested` in libstdc++:

```
template<typename _Except>
struct _Nested_exception : public _Except, public nested_exception
{
  explicit _Nested_exception(_Except&& __ex)
  : _Except(static_cast<_Except&&>(__ex))
  { }
};
```

This derives from your `Derived` class, and attempts to initialize itself with your copy or move constructor, both of which are implicitly defined.

In the case of non-virtual inheritance, this would be fine, since base classes are recursively copied or moved by implicit copy/move constructors, as laid out in the standard:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class `X` performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members.
>
> §12.8 [class.copy]

However, because of the virtual inheritance, and §10.1 [class.mi] (quoted above), it is the responsibility of the base class (in this case `_Nested_exception` to initialize `Base`, **not** the responsibility of your `Derived` class.

Therefore, an attempt is made to find a default constructor, which fails, because it is implicitly deleted, because there is another user-provided constructor, and the standard states:

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted.
>
> §12.1 [class.ctor]

Accordingly this code is **correctly rejected by the compiler**.

Comment: Wait, you point out on my answer that this implementation contradicts the requirements of [except.nested], and then post your own answer saying that because it is implemented like this, the compiler is correct? Does `T` meet the requirements of `throw_with_nested` as specified in the standard? If so, the program must be accepted. If not, it doesn't need to be. How the implementation implements it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @hvd: No, on your answer I commented that this has nothing to do with copy constructors (because of §12.8 [class.copy]), which is correct.

Comment: My answer wasn't using a copy constructor, but neither is `_Nested_exception`: a constructor taking a reference to a base class isn't a copy constructor. The problem for a default constructor and for a random other constructor is exactly the same. But again, that's an implementation detail that shouldn't be relevant here.

Comment: @hvd: Perhaps I misunderstood your answer and you should have clarified rather than deleting it.  I got the impression that your answer was implying that `Derived` should be default constructible, which isn't the case.  Neither `Derived` or `Base` have to be default constructible, **provided there is no virtual inheritance**.  It is the virtual inheritance, not the presence or absence of any constructor, which is preventing this code from compiling.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't what I was trying to say, that's why I included the compiler's error message that showed that `Derived2`'s constructor was attempting to construct `Base`. But I deleted it because the comment you left seemed correct: `U` is `CopyConstructible`, so the program appears to meet the requirements of the standard, and the implementation should accept it. (I don't see how that's possible, but I may be missing something.)

Comment: @hvd: However the standard also states that if the type is not derived from `nested_exception` the implementation will attempt to derive from it and `nested_exception`, and construct that nested class with `std::forward<T>(t)`, which is impossible with the scenario the OP lays out.  You could make an argument that the "*Requires*" specification in the standard should be updated to reflect this, but as written the standard does not allow the OP's code to compile.

Comment: The standard does construct the nested class from `std::forward<T>(t)`, but only implicitly requires a custom constructor for it: by default, such a derived class won't have *any* constructor taking a `T`, and the intent clearly won't be that pretty much any use of `throw_with_nested` be invalid, so implementations are required to add whatever constructors they need, and implement them in such a way as to make `throw_with_nested` work. This seems like it requires compiler magic, when dealing with virtual bases...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you have virtual inheritance, the last derived class is responsible for constructing the base.

In this case, the library is trying to create more classes that derive from yours and then cannot construct them.

When you remove the "virtual" inheritence, the final classes can derive from yours without an issue.

The implementation "code" that is hitting the error message...

```
template<typename _Except>
struct _Nested_exception : public _Except, public nested_exception 
{
  explicit _Nested_exception(_Except&& __ex)
  : _Except(static_cast<_Except&&>(__ex))
 { }
};
```

so it needs in its constructor to construct a `Base` as it is now the most derived class, and isn't able to dp so correctly.